# Magento 1.9 : How to Send Mag::Log error using Whatsapp?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, messages

How can i send my EventObserver log message by whatsapp message?

Comment: you need to use the whatsapp notification extension for that

Comment: Can i get the link for magento 1?

Comment: https://meetanshi.com/magento-whatsapp-notifications.html but its paid extension

Comment: Looking for API